# Git clone over http not asking for authentication

Tags: git

I have implemented a private git server over http using the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) and added a few users.

The problem is that it allows me to clone or pull without authentication it only asks for user and pass when I make a push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation link only restricts pushes because it looks for `git-receive-pack`, which is the push code.  `git-upload-pack` is the clone and fetch code (the names refer to the server's activity).

If you want to restrict all access, remove the line which looks like this:

```
    Require expr !(%{QUERY_STRING} -strmatch '*service=git-receive-pack*' || %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/git-receive-pack$#)
```